# How do I call a method, given its name, on an element of an array?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

How do I call a method, given its name, on an element of an array?

For example, I could have:

```
thing = "each"
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
def do_thing(thing)
  array = [object1,object2]
  array[0].thing
end
```

so that `do_thing(to_s)`, for example, would run `object1.to_s`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `public_send` or `send`. `public_send` only sends to public methods while `send` can see public and private methods.

```
def do_thing(thing)
  array = [1,2,3]
  array.public_send(thing)
end

do_thing('first')
# => 1

do_thing(:last)
# => 3
```

**Update** A more general version:

```
def do_thing(array, index, method, *args)
  array[index].public_send(method, *args)
end

do_thing([1, 2, 3], 0, :to_s)
# => "1"

do_thing([[1,2], [3, 4]], 0, :fetch, 0)
# => 1

require 'ostruct'
o = OpenStruct.new(attribute: 'foo')
do_thing([o], 0, :attribute=, 'bar')
o.attribute == 'bar'
# => true
```

Comment: it's a strange problem, I have an array of objects. I want to be able to choose an object from that array and run a method on it: array[0].public_send(thing) still doesn't work, because it's calling it on array, not on the object in index 0.

Comment: @NoamGagliardi,
`irb(main):007:0> a = 1,2,3`
`irb(main):008:0> a[0].send(:succ)`
`# => 2`
Seems like it's working nicely.

Comment: @NoamGagliardi You want a method like `do_thing(array, index, method)` that is equivalent to `array[index].method`?

Comment: @toro2k that's almost exactly the method I'm trying to get to work. yes.

Comment: @toro2k hm, only problem now is it doesn't work if the method is a setter (so it works for person.name, but nor person.name=) if I want to set the value. -- I also got it to work with array.fetch(method)

Comment: @toro2k thanks. I added another alternative that works with setters that someone here showed me.

Comment: The version you added is the same as my last solution, just using `fetch` instead of `[]`.

Comment: "`You could use public_send (or send if you want to call a private method):`". To say it differently, "You can use `public_send` or `send`. `public_send` only sends to public methods. `send` can see public and private methods." That `send` sees both is convenient and a backdoor to calling private methods from outside the class. It's an advanced technique sometimes used to shoot our feet off. :-)

Answer (score 0):

[Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-send)

```
thing = "each"
def do_thing(thing)
  array = [1,2,3]
  array.send(thing)
end
```

From the doc:

```
class Klass
  def hello(*args)
    "Hello " + args.join(' ')
  end
end
k = Klass.new
k.send :hello, "gentle", "readers"   #=> "Hello gentle readers"
```

Comment: @toro2k : updated my answer. But we can pass symbols too, to the `send` method.

Comment: The problem was just with `:thing = 'each'`

Comment: @toro2k , ah ok, that was in hurry :) but thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to help you out although I don't have any idea what objects are residing inside your array:

```
arr = [Array.new(2,10),"abc" ]
arr.each{|i| p i.send(:length)}
#>>2
#>>3
```